# running an ansible local task in a remote playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get this task to run locally (on the machine that is running the playbook) :

```
- name: get the local repo's branch name
  local_action: git branch | awk '/^\*/{print $2}'
  register: branchName
```

I tried plenty of variations with no success

all other tasks are meant to run on the target host, which is why running the whole playbook local is not an option

```
TASK: [get the local repo's branch name] ************************************** 
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE git branch | awk '/^\*/{print $2}'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407258765.57-75899426008172 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407258765.57-75899426008172 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407258765.57-75899426008172']
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpQVocvw TO /home/max/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407258765.57-75899426008172/git
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', '/usr/bin/python /home/max/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407258765.57-75899426008172/git; rm -rf /home/max/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407258765.57-75899426008172/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
failed: [portal-dev] => {"failed": true}
msg: this module requires key=value arguments (['branch', '|', 'awk', '/^\\*/{print $2}'])

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

#### update:

I have followed bkan's suggestion (bellow), and got a bit further, but

```
  - name: get the local repo's branch name
    local_action: command git branch | (awk '/^\*/{print $2}')
    sudo: no
    register: branchName
```

now the git command gets launched but not correctly (see error below).

note that this command runs perfectly as a "shell" but unfortunately there is no local_shell equivalent of local_action ...

```
failed: [portal-dev] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["git", "branch", "|", "(awk", "/^\\*/{print $2})"], "delta": "0:00:00.002980", "end": "2014-08-05 18:00:01.293632", "rc": 129, "start": "2014-08-05 18:00:01.290652"}
stderr: usage: git branch [options] [-r | -a] [--merged | --no-merged]
   or: git branch [options] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
   or: git branch [options] [-r] (-d | -D) <branchname>...
   or: git branch [options] (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>

...
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The format for local_action is:

```
local_action: <module_name> <arguments>
```

In your example, Ansible thinks you are trying to use the git module and throws an error because you don't have the correct arguments for the git module. Here is how it should look:

```
local_action: shell git branch | awk '/^\*/{print $2}'
```

Source: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation

Comment: thanks, following the syntax did allow me to go a bit further, the git command does get executed, but it fails, it seems to get crippled by the command module

Comment: Just tested this out. If you change command to shell it should work

Comment: @bkan, thanks.  Could you please mention `local_action: shell` in your answer?

Comment: @seanf I've updated the answer to use shell instead of command.

Comment: Thanks @bkan. (At first I thought `local_action: shell` fixed my problem, but it turns out to be a delegation bug: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10906)

Comment: For me, `shell` did not work, but `command` did.  I'm running Ansible version 2.0.1.0.  My playbook line is now `local_action: command ssh root@blog exit` (ssh's into the host and then immediately exits).

Comment: @KeithBennett at the time I wrote this answer, you had to use the `shell` module with git. The key thing here though is that the first argument should be the module name