# Ansible git module rev-parse

Tags: git, ansible

Hi I want to execute the following as ansible task to pull the latest commit id on local:

```
  - name: get latest git commit id
    local_action: "command git rev-parse HEAD"
    register: git_commit_id
```

but I'm getting a warning because I'm using `command`. Since `git` is an ansible core module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html

How can I execute this using git module?

Answer (score 2):

If you put this in your vars file:

```
base: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'git rev-parse --show-toplevel') }}"
```

and then use the variable `{{base}}` in your playbook that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and see if "[running an ansible local task in a remote playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25145827/6309)" applies in your case, using **[delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation)** and the `shell` module:

```
local_action: <module_name> <arguments>
# in your case
local_action: shell git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: not sure I follow, you are still using "shell" module and not "git" module. I get the same warning. Note that the "command" module works too, I just get a warning and was wondering if I can get rid of warning (not supress it)

Comment: @Ankit What warning do you get?

Comment: [WARNING]: Consider using git module rather than running git
I've temporarily disabled it using: 
`local_action: "shell git rev-parse HEAD warn=no"`